# How can 4 GB of data can expand into 40 GB of data, when I install Windows on a Computer

Tags: operating-systems, data-compression

Say I start with an iso with about 4GB of data and use this, to install windows on a computer. After installation, the operating system will take up about 40GB of disk space.

1. Where does all this "extra" data come from? I mean, when all the information can be packed into 4GB, why does it need 40GB in the end?

Comment: `n=1; for k = 1 to 20: n = 1 << n; for k = 0 to n: print(k)` is a short program that, I think, writes all programs ever written plus some numbers that are not programs.

Comment: @justjates windows reserve quite a bit of space for all sorts of things like drivers, updates, backups, space to  handle RAM "overflow", etc. which the system might use in the future. Probably most of your "extra data" is just "extra space" reserved by the OS.